# Datagridview (VB 2010) Readonly property for a column, "strange" behavior

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I encountered a strange behavior with the following code on a datagridview in VB2010. 
`dgv` is the name of the datagridview. In `FormLoad`, I wrote

```
Private Sub frmdataLog_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dgv.ColumnCount = 5
    dgv.Columns(0).Width = 27
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 1 To 4
        dgv.Columns(j).Width = 85
    Next

    dgv.Rows.Add(1)
    dgv.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Sl No."
    dgv.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Test Reading Nm"
    dgv.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Standard Reading Nm"
    dgv.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Error in Nm"
    dgv.Columns(4).HeaderText = "% Uncertainty"
    For j = 0 To 5
        dgv.Columns(j).ReadOnly = True
        dgv.Columns(j).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    Next
    dgv.Columns(1).ReadOnly = False

End Sub
```

I am expecting `column(1)` to be editable while all other columns will be uneditable.

But I found that even `column(1)` is also readonly!

But when I added the following code, the problem got solved:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellEnter
    colVal = e.ColumnIndex
    rowVal = e.RowIndex
    If dgv.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True Then
        dgv.Columns(1).ReadOnly = False
    End If
End Sub
```

My question is why does the line `dgv.Columns(1).ReadOnly = False` not execute under `Form` load?

Comment: Have you set the grid's `ReadOnly` property to `True` somewhere?  If so then that will override the column properties.

Comment: No. Actually I want users to enter only in one column and all other columns must be locked. To add to mystery the same code (exactly same code) runs without any problem in another project.
I am sure of one thing- it is executing anywhere else. But not in FormLoad. But why it is working in another project but not in this project has baffled me.